# Passing off python request cookies to browser

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

In the python program I am making, I have created a requests session that goes through a series of post and get requests to get to the final url with the specific cookies that it has acquired along the way.  My idea is to then have these cookies passed on to a human using a browser.  My question is, how could I go about doing that? I have read about the python http servers and it seems like that may be my best option but I have not found anything that explicitly says it would work.

I need a way to redirect a user to a site with specific cookies.
Any suggestion about how to go about doing that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I only give a short version of what you have to do but i think you will get it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
for c in s.cookies :
    driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value, 'path': c.path, 'expiry': c.expires})
driver.get(url)
```

[Selenium site](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

With the above code you need Firefox installed and [gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) in the same folder as python script.
You also can use Chrome and [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

If you don't want to have geckdriver in the python script path you can have it in c:/program and use

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/Program/geckodriver.exe')
```